# Can't link_to correct path when using nested shallow routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, link-to

I am using nested routes in my rails app. I am successfully able to link through to `clients/:id/invoices/:id` The problem I am running into I think is that I am using shallow routes, so after clicking an `invoice` `show link` my app redirects from `/client/:id` to `/invoice/:id`. Now when I try to go back from this `show` link to my `client_path` I get the two routes mixing up.

for example `invoice/34` becomes `client/34` when I try to `link_to` my client path when it should change to the `clients id`.

I think this might have something to do with my `show` action in my `clients_controller` being `@client = Client.find(params[:id])`

My routes

```
resources :clients do
resources :invoices, shallow: true
end
```

My clients controller show action

```
def show
@client = Client.find(params[:id])
@invoices = @client.invoices
end
```

Clients show.html.erb

```
<% @invoices.where(published: false).each do |invoice| %>
  <tr>
   <td><%= invoice.sender %></td>
   <td><%= invoice.reciever %></td>
   <td><%= invoice.amount %></td>
   <td><%= invoice.currency %></td>
   <td><%= invoice.date %></td>
   <td><%= link_to 'Show', invoice_path(invoice) %></td>
  </tr>                
<% end %>
```

and my invoice show.html.erb

```
<%= link_to 'Back', client_path, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is `client_path` has no idea which `Client` to use, and it's defaulting to `params[:id]`. You probably want your `link_to` to look like this:

`<%= link_to 'Back', client_path(invoice.client), class: "btn btn-primary" %>`

Which explicitly states to use the `Client` associated with this `Invoice`.

Comment: Thanks :) `<%= link_to 'Back', client_path(@invoice.client), class: "btn btn-primary" %>` worked